# Validity of valgrind test that was run prior to optimization flags

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, arm, valgrind

I'm experiencing an issue in which my code is failing to run correctly when under Valgrind and optimization flags turned on.

The executable code I am testing is a simple pared-down wrapper around a numerical computation library I have written. The code does a test on validity and I can print various pieces of debugging information (including the validity of the library result).

When the library is compiled with `-O3` (versus `-O2` or below), the executable run from the command line will run correctly and will output what is expected.

When the same executable is run under valgrind, the outputs are incorrect and valgrind complains about memory accesses (likely due to an interim result being wrong - verified by the printed output - messing with the allocations).

With optimizations `-O2`, everything works fine, both under Valgrind and in isolation.

I am aware of the potential issue of running Valgrind with higher optimizations (though I have not found discussion of the precise problem I'm encountering). In light of that, my question is this:

Can I trust GCC that turning on optimizations will not cause code that passes Valgrind to be made invalid, assuming the other aspects of the testing (i.e. the data validity tests) are still correct?

In other words, do I ever need to run Valgrind with the higher optimizations to be confident that everything that Valgrind tested with the lower optimizations is still ok?

For extra information, the problem is encountered running on ARM 32-bit. On x86 64-bit, everything seems fine on all optimizations.

Comment: High optimization levels can cause generated code to be incorrect, or slower. You could see the [GCC online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) to see what extra flags `-O3` turns on, and then add then one by one when using "only" `-O2`. When your programs stops working as it should you know the flag that caused it. Note the multiple flags can cause weird behavior, or certain combinations of optimizations.

Comment: Also, never debug with optimizations enabled, it can distort the results as well as make stepping through code or setting breakpoints hard or impossible.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, that is clear :) . My question is precisely that: Is there a situation where testing without optimizations results in optimizations possibly causing problems? I've actually tried turning on each flag independently (using the results from `gcc -Q --help=optimizers`, as well as the docs you reference) and I can't replicate the problem!

Comment: Sure, there's positively _loads_ of undefined behaviour that you in practice get away with up to the point where one particularly aggressive optimisation suddenly pulls the rug out from under you. See all the old horror stories about shipping the debug build of the application because the release build wouldn't work...

Comment: Perhaps `-pedantic` is my friend here...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've actually traced this down to a `-mtune=cortex-a9` flag (and contrary to my earlier assertion, the code was broken outside of valgrind, it just wasn't obvious).